# Is there some kind of reverse Foreign Key relationship in Django?

Tags: django, database, many-to-many, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have two models like:

```
class Task(models.Model):
  ...

class MilageReceipt(models.Model):
  ...
```

Every Receipt is supposed to list a lot of tasks. This could be done quickly with a ForeignKeyField("MilageReceipt") on the Task model. But the Receipt is generated much later and because I want to select the Tasks while creating it I'd prefer to have the Receipt link to the Tasks it lists and not the other way round. I could use a ManyToMany relationship here, but then I'd need to verify all the time that no Task has been billed twice. In a single word I need a ManyToOneRelation.

I'm sure this is a common problem. What is the most straightforward way to solve this? I especially want to avoid having to massively modify the admin.

Sorry, I'm sure there are other questions like this, but I didn't find a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id=models.CharField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,max_length=100)

class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
```

In this case you can use post.comments to get all the comments.

Comment: This `ForeignKey` would work, but I would not override the `id` field in the `Post` model unless it is absolutely necessary.